# Types & exceptions for a generic function to return an object or raise exception from QuerySet with a single item?

Tags: python, types, django-queryset, typing

I have a pattern in my project where I need to re-use filtering logic for returning multiple results and a single result (depending on the input and needs of the caller).  I'd like to make some generic function that takes a QuerySet as its input and either returns the only item in it or raises an exception like `Model.objects.get()` does if the number of results is not 1.

```py
def single_result_from_qset(qset: "QuerySet") -> Any:
    """TODO: make this work somehow"""
    if len(qset) > 1:
        raise qset.MultipleObjectsReturned
    try:
        return qset[0]
    except IndexError:  # this is not unreachable, no matter what PyCharm tells you
        raise qset.DoesNotExist
```

The problem I have with the above code I've tried arises when I need to raise an error.  Instead of raising the error I asked it to, I get an `AttributeError` because neither `MultipleObjectsReturned` nor `DoesNotExist` are attributes of a `QuerySet`.  How do I raise these errors from the objects the QuerySet is acting on?

As a bonus question, what is the proper type signature for the function definition?

Comment: Pretty much immediately after asking this, I found out about the QuerySet.get()—I’ll post a fleshed-our answer tomorrow once I have access to a full keyboard again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution is to use [`.get()` from `QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) rather than implement a new helper function.  `.get()` returns and throws exactly what I was asking the above helper function to do.

Instead of calling `rabbit = single_result_from_qset(search_animals_by_meat("Haßenpferrer))`, I can use `rabbit = search_animals_by_meat("Haßenpferrer).get()`.
`search_animals_by_meat(q: str) -> "QuerySet[Animal]"` could be a wrapper for something like `Animals.objects.filter(meat_name__icontains=q)` or a far more complex filtering scheme.